# Facebook commenting not synced

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

I am struggling to see a working example of facebook commenting syncing comments with facebook posts. The following is extracted from: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

> Friends and people who like the Page can then respond to the
>   discussion by liking or replying to the comment directly in the News
>   Feed on Facebook or in the Comments Box on your site. Threads stay
>   synced across Facebook and on the Comments Box on your site regardless
>   of where the comment was made.

As an example, check out any techcrunch article on their facebook page: http://www.facebook.com/techcrunch?fref=ts If you click a link to view an article on their website, the comments are completely different and don't seem to be synced at all.

Can anyone shed some light on (A) if comments can be properly synced (B) how it is done.

I have an app set up with sandboxing on. If I comment on an article on my site, then post a link to that article on our facebook page, I would expect the comments on our site and the comments on the shared article to be the same?